# Scroll Only the Child Eelement

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to set scrolling only in child div. I have fixed height for the parent div with `overflow-y: hidden;` yet scroll taller the child div using `overflow-y: scroll;`.

However, that shows a disabled scroll bar through the Y-Axis of the child div. How can I make it work using CSS only? If not, is there any jQuery way?

Here is the code I am using at the moment:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And, the CSS:

```
.parent {
  display: block;
  height: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* So that the child doesn't break layout */
  width: 400px;
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  display: block;
  height: 1500px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Make the child scroll */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the child doesn't have overflow. You are making the height 1500px, thus the parent has overflow because the child is 1500px tall. If you replace the height with `height:100%`, change `overflow-y:scroll` to `overflow:auto`, and add content to make it overflow [**it works properly**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/NM7R7/) just as you have it

Side notes:

- For divs do not need to declare `display:block` because it is innate with the element type
- You should use `box-sizing: border-box` on elements that have width or height 100% and that the parents have padding in order to make them take up 100% of the width or height *minus* the padding

Comment: Thanks man!! That worked perfectly. Also, the notes are duly taken. Thanks once again.